# Adding comments to a SQL query in FileNet Content Engine

Tags: filenet-content-engine, filenet-cpe, filenet-ce-sql

Is it possible to add comments to a query, in FileNet?
I refer, in particular, to queries written via FEM.
I have searched on the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/it/SSNW2F_4.5.1/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/guide/query_sql_syntax_ref.htm), but I have found nothing about it.

I have a large query, and I wish to add comments for its subqueries in order to keep it documented.

```
-- I am trying the "classic" approach with the double dash
```

but with no luck.